# Can someone explain the “the groundskeeper went to Cornell“ joke?

Tags: the-office

[*The Office: Weight Loss*](https://theoffice.fandom.com/wiki/Weight_Loss) (S05E01) contains the following quote:

> **Andy:** *Hey, check it out. [hands her a brochure] This is The Breakers, Newport, Rhode Island. Huge, awesome gorgeous mansion overlooking the Atlantic. **And my dad went to Cornell with the current groundskeeper**..*

[Cornell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornell_University) is part of the Ivy League. If someone attends this school they should be overqualified for a job as Groundskeeper. Is this supposed to be a joke? If so, can you explain it to me?

Comment: I'm assuming the joke is that it's so incredibly exclusive that even the *groundskeeper* went to an Ivy League university.

Comment: Or conversely, that a Cornell degree is so worthless that it qualifies you to work as a groundskeeper.

Comment: They don't seem to be very complimentary about Cornell on the show; https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&client=ms-android-google&source=android-browser&q=inurl%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ftranscripts.foreverdreaming.org+%22follows+the+everyday+lives%22+%22Cornell%22

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a running joke on The Office that Andy is excessively proud of having attended Cornell and frequently shoehorns it into conversations. The joke here is that the groundskeeper connection is such a tenuous one that has no reason to be mentioned otherwise, it's just a way for Andy to bring up Cornell.